# Sum of formula results of past integers in Excel

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried looking for other similar questions but I'm not knowledgeable enough about math XD

I'm working on a game where the character experience for next level is derived by the following formula (currently using excel)

> =49+(n^1.7)

where n is the target cell in excel, the character's level.

I want to apply the following sort of functionality, so that I can calculate the sum of all past character experience, not just the current experience required.

> =n*(n+1)/2

This is a basic formula that gets you the sum of past integers, but replacing n with my first formula makes it try to sum up 49 integers. I'm not knowledgeable about math or excel to proceed...

Example: at Level 1, the total should be 50 (rounded). At Level 5, the total should be 281. I can figure this out manually, but I need a formula to do it.

Can anyone help? Should I be looking into factorial math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding a closed formula for the sum is problematic:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (49+k^{1.7})$$
In MS Excel, you can enter the formulas as shown:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks, that would work if I wanted to keep the table, but I was hoping to have the final sum calculated from a single cell. I only had the table going on for the purpose of figuring out the formulas.

If doing a closed formula for this isn't possible, I'll look into having the level list in a separate file/tab, and having my single-cell refer to it using if/then logic instead. I'll need to brush up on my excel notation XD

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to compute this in Excel, put 0 in each of the first 3 columns of row 1. In row 2, put:

A2:  = A1 + 1

B2:  = ROUND(49 + (A2^1.7), 0)

C2:  = C1 + B2

Now you can copy those three cells in row 2 and then select as many additional rows from row 3 down as you want and paste.  In row 6, you should see computed 5, 64, 281.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around in excel, still not sure if it's possible to resolve with a single math formula, but I'll mark as resolved.